# Which condition is more general than the other one?

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity, compactness, weak-convergence

I have a result which is true for the two following conditions, and I want to know which one is more general than the other one.

Let $T$ be a operator from $E$ into itself ($E $ is a Banach spaces).

$$(\mathcal{A}) \quad\left\{\begin{array}{l}T \text{ is continuous and verifies:  if}\left(x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { is a weakly convergent sequence in } E, \text { then } \\ \left(T x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { has a strongly convergent subsequence in } \mathcal{X}\end{array}\right.$$

$$(\mathcal{B} )\left\{\begin{array}{l}\text { If }\left(x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { is a weakly convergent sequence in } E, \text { then } \\ \left(T x_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { has a weakly convergent subsequence in } E\end{array}\right.$$

I mean which one implies the other one (if there is an implication between them)?
If there are some examples, I will be very grateful.

Comment: (B) is equivalent to the continuity of $T$.

Answer (score 0):

($\mathcal{A}$) $\implies$ ($\mathcal{B}$) and not vice versa.

The implication ($\mathcal{A}$) $\implies$ ($\mathcal{B}$) is obvious as any strongly convergent subsequence of $(T x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is also weakly convergent.

To see that the other implication does not hold consider $E = \ell^2$ and $T = id$. This operator obviously satisfies $(\mathcal{B})$ but does not satisfy $(\mathcal{A})$. To see this, consider $x_n = e_n$ where $e_n$ is a sequence with $1$ on the $n^{th}$ coordinate and $0$ on other coordinates. Then $x_n$ converges weakly to zero but has no weakly convergent subsequence.